# Create Associations with FactoryBot/Factory Girl in Rails

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

I have three factories that are associated with each other: The `Country` class has a States class and the `States` has a `City` class.

countries.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
factory :country do
    name { Faker::Address.unique.country }
  end
end
```

states.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
factory :state do
    association :country
    name { Faker::Address.state }
  end
end
```

cities.rb

```
   FactoryBot.define do
    factory :city do
        association :state
        name { Faker::Address.city }
      end
    end
```

In my spec I want to instantiate specific objects.

```
  before(:each) do
    create(:city, name:"Buffalo")
    create(:state, name:"New York")
    create(:country, name:"United States")

  end
```

How would I associate the country United States to the State of New York and the State of New York to the city Buffalo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass each object as an attribute of another factory.

```
before(:each) do
  country = create(:country, name:"United States")
  state = create(:state, name:"New York", country: country)
  create(:city, name:"Buffalo", state: state)
end
```

But this leaves you without a means to access these test objects. Instead, use a [`let!`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) for each object.

```
let!(:country) { create(:country, name:"United States") }
let!(:state) { create(:state, name:"New York", country: country) }
let!(:city) { create(:city, name:"Buffalo", state: state) }
```

Now you can refer to `country`, `state`, and `city` in your examples. Unless you specifically need to have your objects created for your tests, you should probably use `let` and allow them to be created on demand.

Finally, we can save a bunch of work by inverting this. Create a City, then retrieve the state from the city and the country from the state.

```
let(:city) { create(:city) }
let(:state) { city.state }
let(:country) { state.country }
```

And instead of specifying the exact names, you can reference `city.name` in your tests. For example.

```
let(:city) { create(:city) }
let(:state) { city.state }
let(:country) { state.country }

describe '#find_city' do
  it 'finds a city by name' do
    expect( country.find_city(city.name) ).to eq city
  end
end

describe '#find_state' do
  it 'finds a state by name' do
    expect( country.find_state(state.name) ).to eq state
  end
end
```

Comment: this is a great explanation. Thanks! 
I have a method that checks if a city exists, if it doesn't it creates it. Hence why I need to create a pre-existing city to check for an edge case. For that scenario, I wouldn't need to use the ! correct? And would I need to clean the factory out? Thanks

Comment: @lost9123193 `let` runs on demand. `let!` runs before each example. Both only run once per example and cache the result, so you'll only get one city. If you need a city to already exist for a test, use `let!`, or use `let` and `before { city }`. And no, there's no need to clean out your database, rspec should do that for you. Each example runs in a transaction and rolls back at the end.